# Error in running IEPY preprocess.py script on Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x

I have installed Python package IEPY on Windows 10, Python version (3.5.4, 32-bit). l am getting following error while running preprocess.py script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "scripts\test2\bin\preprocess.py", line 88, in 
start_preprocess(all_docs, increment_ner)
File "scripts\test2\bin\preprocess.py", line 39, in start_preprocess
StanfordPreprocess(increment_ner),
File "C:\Users\Erum\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\iepy\preprocess\stanford_preprocess.py", line 84, in init
self.corenlp = corenlp.get_analizer(gazettes_filepath=gazettes_filepath)
File "C:\Users\Erum\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\iepy\preprocess\corenlp.py", line 56, in get_analizer
return StanfordCoreNLP(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Erum\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\iepy\preprocess\corenlp.py", line 67, in init
self._start_proc()
File "C:\Users\Erum\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\iepy\preprocess\corenlp.py", line 75, in _start_proc
cwd=_FOLDER_PATH
File "C:\Users\Erum\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 676, in init
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "C:\Users\Erum\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 957, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.